# Dispatch Source Reader - How to detect End-Of-File?

Tags: c, cocoa, file-io, grand-central-dispatch

Inspired by [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW6), I'm experimenting with using a GCD dispatch source to read asynchronously from a file, instead of using the traditional `NSInputStream` and run loop based approach.

However, I'm not sure how to detect when I'm done reading the file. With `NSInputStream`, your delegate get sent a `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` event. For dispatch sources, I assumed the event handler would get called at the end-of-file, but this doesn't seem to be the case. What am I missing?

Here's my code:

```
const char* fileName = "/Users/Nick/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml";
int fd = open(fileName, O_NONBLOCK|O_RDONLY);
assert(fd>0);

dispatch_source_t readerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, fd, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(readerSource, ^{
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t estimatedLength = dispatch_source_get_data(readerSource);

    ssize_t bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, MIN(1024, estimatedLength));
    if (bytesRead < 0) {
        if (errno != EAGAIN) {
            printf("Unexpected error!");
            abort();
        }
    } else if (bytesRead > 0) {
        printf("Got %ld bytes of data.\n", bytesRead);
    } else {
        // bytesRead == 0
        printf("EOF encountered!\n");
        dispatch_source_cancel(readerSource);
    }
});

dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(readerSource, ^{
    printf("Cancel handler was called.\n");
    close(fd);
    dispatch_release(readerSource);
});

dispatch_resume(readerSource);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you have to compare read bytes with the length of the file.

Besides, GCD dispatch source uses kqueue with EVFILT_READ, thus it is not really useful for regular files. I recommend you to use open/lseek/read/close a file in Global Queue.

- [Re: kqueue and EVFILT_READ on files](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Unix-porting/2006/Jan/msg00040.html)

  > For the most part, read filters are not really useful for regular files, since - well - they are always readable, so long as they have data remaining in them, and they will give a clear EOF condition. You can't really treat files as if they were pipes - i.e. don't expect a fle whose fp is at EOF that then gets extended so there is more data in the file to result in an EVFILT_READ coming true. This will work in the non-EV_POLL case, for regular files, but it's not going to work for special files.
  >
  > Likewise, at least for most normal block devices (disks, etc.), the are also always readable until you hit the end of the device, and there's a clear EOF indication there, too, so they are not too useful there, either (it's not like more disk blocks will suddenly be arriving on a platter that was built in 1998, for example).

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of the "regular file" distinction.